# Парсинг динамического сайта Selenium Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

Мне нужно получить цифры с сайта на JS:

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars") 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)

for http in alldict:
    browser.get(http)
    page = browser.page_source
    print(page)
```

Но в page хранятся необработанные данные по типу:

```
$('#' + moduleType + 'Name').html(vars.chassises[module_id].chassis_name);
```

Как получить цифры вместо названий?

Comment: Сейчас уже не очень помню но посмотрите там должно быть что-то типа `get_attribute('innerHTML')` (или outerHTML) ну или что-то похожее. Погуглите. Давно уже selenium не юзал

Answer (score 0):

В принципе есть идея прогнать в цикле количество страниц, и после каждой итерации наполнять переменную `pages` на +1, в итоге в конце цикла мы получим количество страниц, и при этом ничего не нужно обрезать и танцевать с бубном

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars") 
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=option)

pages = 0

for http in alldict:
    browser.get(http)
    page = browser.page_source
    pages += 1
print (pages)
```